# Forget Password Customized forget password in yii

Tags: yii

I am very new in YII framework. I want to add "Forget Password" along with the login form. When user click on it, system will fetch email address of that user from the database and send new Password to that user by email. I don't want to use any plug-ins for that.

This is my link code:-

```
        <?php echo CHtml::Link(Yii::t('job','Forgot Password ?'),
                                $this->createUrl('site/forgotpassword'),
                                array(
                                    'onclick'=>'$("#jobDialog").dialog("open"); return false;',
                                    'update'=>'#jobDialog'
                                ),
                                array('id'=>'showJobDialog'));?>
<div id="jobDialog"></div>
```

This is my site controller:-

```
public function actionForgotPassword()
{
    $model  = new User;
    $this->renderPartial('createDialog',array('model'=>$model,),false,true);
}
```

This is my createdialog.php:-

```
<?php 

$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
                'id'=>'jobDialog',
                'options'=>array(
                    'title'=>Yii::t('job','Fogot Password ?'),
                    'autoOpen'=>true,
                    'modal'=>'true',
                    'width'=>'auto',
                    'height'=>'auto',
                ),
                ));
echo $this->renderPartial('_formDialog', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
<?php $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');?>
```

This is my _formDialog.php

```
<div class="form" id="jobDialogForm">
 <style type="text/css">
.forgot_password{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 5px 3px;
    width:70%;
}
label{
    color: #575757;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0 0 0 3px;
    }
</style>
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                                            'id'=>'job-form',
                                            'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
                                )); 
//I have enableAjaxValidation set to true so i can validate on the fly the
?>
    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
    <!---flash message start------>
<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('error')):?>
        <div class="alert alert-error">
                <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('error'); ?>
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<!----flash message end----->
    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>180,'class'=>'forgot_password')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(Yii::t('job','Submit'),CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('site/forgotpassword1','render'=>false)),array('success'=>'js: function(data) {
                        $("#jobDialog").dialog("close");
                    }'),array('id'=>'closeJobDialog','onclick'=>'return forgotpassword()')); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function forgotpassword()
    {
        var email           = $("#User_email").val();
        if(email=='')
        { 
            $("#errorEmail").remove();
             $('#User_email').after('<div class="errorMessage" id="errorEmail">Email should not be blank.</div>');
             return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#errorEmail").remove();
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you think about how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your controller,

```
private function randomPassword() {
    $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
    $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
        $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
    }
    return implode($pass); //turn the array into a string
}

public function actionForgotPassword($email) {
    $user = User::model()->findAll('email=:email',
                array('email'=>$email);

    if(count($user) != 1) {
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('user',
            Yii::t('messages', 'Unable to find user.'));
        );
        $this->refresh();
    }
    else {
        $user = $user[0];
        $user->password = $this->randomPassword();
        $user->update();

        // Send new password to email
        $from = 'Password Reset <admin@yoursite.com>';
        $to = $user->email;
        $name = $user->firstname.' '.$user->lastname;
        $subject = 'Reset Password';

        $message = Yii::t('user', 'Dear').' '.$user->username.',
'.Yii::t('user', 'A request has been made to reset your password.').'
'.Yii::t('user', 'Your new password is').': '.$user->password.'
'; // Our message above

        $headers = 'From: '.$from."\r\n"; // Set from headers
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send our email

        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('user',
            Yii::t('notices', 'A new password has been sent to your email address.')
        );
        $this->refresh();
    }

    $this->layout = '//layouts/main';
    $this->render('resetpassword');
}
```

Also add a view "resetpassword.php":

```
<div class="flash-success">
    <?= Yii::app()->user->getFlash('user') ?>
</div>
```

Comment: hello @samuel liew , i have created one link for forgot password? if i click on that then 1 pop up is opening with email and submit button

Comment: show me the link for forgot password link please as soon as possible